# Cannot pass a Collection<> as a parameter in Spring Boot constructor injection

Tags: spring-boot

I have a repository with this method:

```
@Query("SELECT "
    + "NEW com.caido.appointments.entity.DTO.AppointmentDTO("
        + " a.id AS id,"
        + " NEW com.caido.appointments.entity.DTO.SimplePhysicianDTO(p.id, p.stencilNo, p.idPersonnel.imagineAngajat, p.idPersonnel.idperson.name, p.idPersonnel.idperson.surname, pr.idSex, p.idPersonnel.id, d.id) AS physician, "
        + " a.idSpeciality AS speciality, "
        + " false AS hasAssociatedConsultation,"
        + " false AS canceled,"
        + " a.oraProgramare AS oraProgramare,"
        + " a.labTestsGroups, "
    + ") "
    + "FROM Appointments a "
    + "JOIN Physicians p ON (p.id = a.idPhysicians.id) "
    + "JOIN Personnel pe ON (pe.id = p.idPersonnel.id) "
    + "JOIN PersonnelDepartment pd ON (pd.idPersonnel = pe.id and pd.validFrom <= date(a.oraProgramare) AND (pd.validTo >= date(a.oraProgramare) OR pd.validTo IS NULL)) "
    + "JOIN Department d ON (d.id = pd.idDepartment and d.idSpeciality = a.idSpeciality.id AND d.ambulatoriu = 1 ) "
    + "JOIN Person pr ON (pr.id = pe.idperson.id) "
    + "WHERE a.idPerson.id = ?1 "
    + "ORDER BY a.oraProgramare")
List<AppointmentDTO> getConnectedUserAppointments(Integer idPerson, Pageable pageable);
```

Facts:

- The constructor of AppointmentDTO has the last parameter of the type  Collection of LabTestsGroups.
- The field labTestsGroups from the class Appointments is of the type Collection of LabTestsGroups
- This field from the constructor(a.labTestsGroups) generates the error "**Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found and one or more arguments did not define alias for bean-injection**". If I delete this field from the constructor of AppointmentDTO and from the query the error is gone.

Why can't I map a.labTestsGroups in my AppointmentDTO constructor, they are of the same type.

I also tried to replace + " a.labTestsGroups, " with a subquery like this:

```
+ " (SELECT lt FROM AppointmentsLabTestsGroups altg JOIN LabTestsGroups lt ON (lt.id = altg.idLabTestsGroups.id) WHERE altg.idAppointment.id = a.id) AS servicii, "
```

and even like this:

```
+ " (SELECT NEW com.caido.appointments.entity.LabTestsGroups(lt.id, lt.code, lt.name) FROM AppointmentsLabTestsGroups altg JOIN LabTestsGroups lt ON (lt.id = altg.idLabTestsGroups.id) WHERE altg.idAppointment.id = a.id) AS servicii,
```

But then I got the error: "**Unable to determine dynamic instantiation injection strategy for com.caido.appointments.entity.DTO.AppointmentDTO#servicii**"

Comment: Why. How should hibernate make that collection of elements? You cannot map it to a collection like that, you can only map elements of a row not group them together like this.